# How to Set and Update a List Property in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to know if it's possible to update a list property of a node or edge by index.

```
MATCH (t1:t)-[r1:o]->(a:a)<-[r2:o]-(t2:t) where r1.loc-r2.loc=-1 and r1.month=r2.month
WITH t1,t2,count(t1) as c
MERGE (t1)-[r:r]->(t2)
ON CREATE SET r.weights = "empty array of size 12(months) with array[month]=c
ON MATCH  SET r.weights[month] = r.weights[month]+c
```

I suppose one can achieve setting the empty array with something similar to:

```
ON CREATE SET r.weights = reduce(a=[], i in range(0,month-1) | a + [0])+[c]+reduce(a=[], i in range(0,12-month) | a + [0])
```

But what's the best way to update the list property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the following way:

```
MATCH (t1:t)-[r1:o]->(a1:a)<-[r2:o]-(t2:t) where r1.loc-r2.loc=-1 and r1.month=r2.month

WITH t1,r1,t2,r2,count(t1) as c

MERGE (t1)-[r:r]->(t2)

ON CREATE SET r.weights = reduce(a=[], i in range(0,r1.month-2) | a + [0])+[c]+reduce(a=[], i in range(0,11-r1.month) | a + [0])

ON MATCH SET r.weights = reduce(a=[], e in r.weights[0..r1.month-1]+[r.weights[r1.month-1]+c]+r.weights[r1.month..13] |a+e)
return t1,t2,c,r
```